# How to Prevent an Authorized User from Accessing REST APIs using Dev Tools in an SPA

Tags: rest, security, jwt, google-chrome-devtools, single-page-application

We are developing a financial application using SPA architecture. The client and API use the same domain. There are many posts on how to secure REST APIs using JWTs, httpOnly cookies and oAuth which protect the API from external attackers. However, I have not seen a specific discussion of how to prevent knowledgable, authenticated users from hacking APIs from the browser's dev tools. For example, when a user logs in using the login form a JWT is returned and must be stored somewhere on the client. Even if that token is stored in an httpOnly cookie (and inaccessible to JavaScript) the browser still sends it back to the server automatically regardless of how the API call was made (from JavaScript in the SPA client or JavaScript in the console). A valid login to the application does not imply full access to all APIs. What are some specific approaches to mitigate this vulnerability?

Comment: Apply `Authorization` on server, what you are talking about is only authentication

Comment: Sever authentication for each REST end-point still does not solve the problem. In order to get a proper authorization (API key, etc) the JWT still needs to be used. There's no way that I know of to determine if a request came from the client app or from the console.

Comment: It should not matter, if user is authorized he/she should get the data, be it from app or from dev-tools.

Comment: Our app is a financial app so there are different types of users. For example, AR clerk logs in to the app and enters an invoice, the app will use many API calls to process the data but the user should not have direct access any of those APIs. To save an invoice the transaction, account, customer, and setup APIs must all be used. But you really don't what that clerk going in and directly accessing all transactions.

Comment: add whatever checks you need to the API that you want to control. Web as such, specifially APIs, should be stateless. Please read more about securing API. SO cannot help you much about this.

Comment: So, the solution is that each individual application/form (invoice, payment, bill, etc) must provide specific permissions for each endpoint used in that individual application (form) and it must done on the server, probably with a separate JWT for each application so the data accessible through the APIs for each application (via the JWT) matches precisely the data that the user has access to in the UI for that specific application/form. I was hoping for a shortcut. Looks like that does not exist. Thx

Comment: perfect... thats what you need, no shortscuts :)